# Experience with using Aurora RDS for Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, aws

We are looking at using Aurora RDS for new Magento 2 implementations, however, I have not found many people posting about their experiences with it on-line. Amazon claims that it is a "drop-in replacement for MySQL", but I was looking to see what everyone's real-world experience is with the database.

1. I know that we will have to change all of the tables to be InnoDB, but are there any other changes we should make?
2. What about using read-replicas. Aurora is supposed to be faster with syncing, but is it fast enough?
3. Is it noticeably faster than MySQL or MariaDB in real-world usage, not just during load tests?

Answer (score 3):

We are using Aurora with Magento1 and its working fine for us. No need to change anything in your database for migration just restore your mysqldump. Note that we did'nt have nay myisam table (catalogtextfullsearch etc, using solr).

Readreplica do not use typical mysql replication instead they use the common storage as master (writer) so replica lag is always around 20ms as advertised. If writer fails the failover (promoting reader to writer / master) is also very fast usually takes around a min.

Cant say anything about the performance vs mysql as we found it mix in different workloads and scenarios.